# Contacts Framework. Access to phones ' values

Tags: ios, contacts

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.givenName = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSArray *KeysToFetch = @[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey ];
    NSString *containerId = [[[CNContactStore alloc]init]defaultContainerIdentifier];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [CNContact predicateForContactsInContainerWithIdentifier:containerId];

    _contacts = [[[CNContactStore alloc]init]unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate:predicate keysToFetch:KeysToFetch error:nil];

    for (CNContact *c  in _contacts) {

        [_givenName addObject:c.givenName];
        NSLog(@"%@", c.phoneNumbers);
    }
}
```

Hi, how can I get access to the 'digits' value? when i do a NSLog of 'phoneNumbers' i get this on console:

```
2015-10-19 12:33:41.423 testContacts[7064:2001002] (
"<CNLabeledValue: 0x7b72eed0: identifier=A73ABAA0-7698-47D7-A2BD-630E04C0C811, label=_$!<Mobile>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x7b734db0: countryCode=us, digits=8885555512>>",
"<CNLabeledValue: 0x7b72eb80: identifier=BC927A1D-AA98-4E67-82A9-BB5AD09A6CAE, label=_$!<Home>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x7b72ecd0: countryCode=us, digits=8885551212>>"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The digits are a private variable.
For getting a phone number:

```
CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber*>* labeledValue = contact.phoneNumbers[0];
NSString *phone = labeledValue.value.stringValue;
```

E.g. to get a mobile number:

```
// get mobile
NSString *phone = nil;
for (CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber*>* labeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers)
{
    if ([labeledValue.label isEqualToString:CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile])
    {
        phoneNumber = labeledValue.value.stringValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If the phone number is localized with phone characters like `1 (234) 456-78`, stringValue returns exactly that string.

To obtain the digits, the correct code (in Swift) is

```
(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value as! CNPhoneNumber).valueForKey("digits") as! String
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you indicate how you found this syntax even though it looks straight forward?  I tried for hours before I saw this.

Comment: Could you explain why: "let temp:CNPhoneNumber  = contact.phoneNumbers[0].value" won't work?  It has a converting issue to NSCopying, NSSecureCoding.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there another way of accessing this property? Using value for key doesn't seem like a reliable way to go about it. What if the key name "digits" changes?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Swift 2.1. / Xcode 7.2. and iOS 9.2.1.

1. `import ContactsUI`

Import the contacts framework at the bottom of your file

2. *Get your contacts from your addressBook*

This is my example:

> let contacts = XXXContactsAccessManagerM.sharedContacts.getAll()

3. Add this code to the class `Model` or `ViewController` in which you are working

   ```
   for var ctcCtr = 0 ; ctcCtr < contacts.count ; ctcCtr++
   {
       let contact = contacts[ctcCtr]
       let phoneNumbers = contact.phoneNumbers

       for var phnCtr = 0 ; phnCtr < phoneNumbers.count ; phnCtr++
       {
           let phoneNumberLabel = phoneNumbers[phnCtr]
           let phoneNumber = (phoneNumberLabel.value as! CNPhoneNumber).valueForKey("digits") as! String
           print(phoneNumber)
       }
   }
   ```

I got a normal phone number, the exact way I wrote them in my phone book `097XXXXXXX` and so on... (with out hte (XXX) and XXX-XXX)

Comment: Is there another way of accessing this property? Using value for key doesn't seem like a reliable way to go about it. What if the key name "digits" changes?

Comment: One solution would be to check all the keys and then check the values. If the values resemble a phone number than the "key" can be used to find all other phone numbers. This way you can protect your code from the possibility that the keyword changes. However, since apple is using it I doubt that it would change in the near future. Anyway, you are right. From the hardware perspective it might change since Apple is going to ditch the SIM card.

Comment: Lifesaver answer. I was searching for the answer from yesterday. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using [KPKContacts](https://github.com/pavankataria/KPKContacts) package was simple as calling
`contact.firstNumberAvailable()` which returns a String value

or you can do `contact.numbers.first!.number`

Answer (score 0):

This code very helpful for getting both Phone number value and phone number label in swift 3.1

```
let ContactNumber: NSString = (phoneNumber.value).value(forKey:"digits") as! NSString
print(ContactNumber)

let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue<NSString>.localizedString(forLabel: phoneNumber.label!)
print(localizedLabel)
```